# Broken step on staircase

Tags: carpet, stairs, carpentry, fitting

We have a broken step on our carpeted staircase.  How can I remove then refit the carpet without damaging it?  When the carpet has been removed, I will have to repair the step if possible, then refit the carpet.

Comment: Are your stairs a prefabricated setup, where the risers and treads support each other from the sides, or are the stringers underneath?  Is your carpet on the steps in a continuous roll (tread to riser to tread to riser etc) or does each riser/tread pair have its own piece of carpet?  These are all questions that you'll need to know the answers to to see how how easily this can be done and with how little damage.

Comment: These are good questions that need to be asked before giving a proper answer for the best solution. +1

Answer (score 1):

Staple or tack the carpet to the bottom side of the tread above the broken tread, just past where you staple it, cut it with a sharp carpet knife and peal it back, fix the broken tread and then pull the carpet back in place and staple it back into place.  Since all of the stapling and cutting will be on the underside of tread it shouldn't be very noticeable.

Or hire a carpet guy on craigslist or something to come and pull all of it up and relay it for you after you've fixed it. I assume this would cost about $100.